# How to count dynamically inputs value?

Tags: jquery

I got a list with foreach loop in php that got N people in it.
For every person in that list i create dynamically inputs.How to reset var total when i change to another `<div class="inputs">`
**HTML PART:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 taskblock">
<div class="name">User</div> 
    <form>
        <div class="inputs">
            <div><input name="1-quantity" data-id="4" id="test" class="field" value="0" type="text"></div>
        </div>
        User
        <div class="inputs">
            <div><input name="2-quantity" data-id="3" id="test" class="field" value="0" type="text"></div>
        </div>

        <input name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" type="button">
    </form>
```

and the Jquery Part i'm trying with:

```
   function getInt(str) {
  return isNaN(str) || $.trim(str) == "" ? 0 : parseInt(str, 10);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
var total = 0;
  $(".inputs").on('keyup', '.field', function(e) {
    var val = getInt($(this).val());
        var max = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log(max);
    total = 0;
    $(".field").each(function() {
      total += getInt($(this).val());
      if ($(this).val() =="") $(this).remove();
    });
    console.log(total);
    if (total > 0 && total < max) {
        $(this).parent().append('<div><input type="text" data-id="4" class="field" id="test" name="dynamic[]" value="" /></div>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Its not what i'm looking for i think

Comment: put php aside.I'm talking for pure jquery.Now the code is counting all the inputs not only for a single person.